# Swift: Problems printing out UILabel.text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

So I have this routine that sets different text uilabel.text values

```
self.addressLabel.text = firstObject["ADDRESS"] as? String
self.phoneLabel.text = firstObject["PhoneNums"] as? String
self.latitude.text = firstObject["LAT"] as? String
self.longitude.text = firstObject["LON"] as? String
```

but when I try to print out

```
println("\(latitude.text!)")
```

It outputs:

```
Label
```

How can I make it so that the println statement prints the string "38.1848392". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the string to a variable, and then print that.

So:

```
var latitudeString : String = self.latitude.text
println(latitudeString)
```

Edit:

Seems like casting the latitude as a String is not properly happening. What you could do is the following:

```
var lat : Float = firstObject["LAT"] as! Float
var latString = String(lat)
self.latitude.text = latString
println(latString)
```

Comment: Tried it. Didn't do it :( still get the same output when printLn

Comment: what happens when you do `println(firstObject["LAT"])`?

Comment: That actually prints.

Comment: It's because he's trying to cast a `Double` to a `String` using `as` which will always fail (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a `Double` to `String` as it will always fail.

```
self.latitude.text = 38.1848392 as? String            // this will always fail
self.latitude.text = String(format:"%f", 38.1848392)  // instead, you have to do it this way
```